# Can you play all the HD remake collections on Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

I just bought the Jak HD collection and I was wondering if it's playable on the Vita in any way?

If not directly is there some remote play function?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The HD Classic Collections are not playable on the PS Vita, and they don't work over remote play.

Comment: @SirYakalot agreed. I don't understand the restriction, myself, as Remote Play is little more than a remote desktop application... it's possible they'll change it in a future update.

Comment: @SirYakalot and as hope on the horizon, they've stated at least one future remaster (FFX) will be available on Vita.

Comment: Remote play isn't just remote desktop, it actually does some content conversion before transferring it to the PSP/Vita, mainly compressing graphics and downsampling sound and also some changing of controls (for example, in the case of Lair which had to remove SIXAXIS control). In the case of video/music and PS1 games, this conversion is fairly simple. In the case of PS3 software, it requires actual implementation in the software itself.

Comment: Plus, neither PSP nor Vita have triggers (R2/L2), and PSP surely does not have analog sticks buttons (R3/L3). Are PS Vita sticks equipped with button functionality BTW?

Comment: Vita has the ability to map R2/L2 and R3/L3 to certain areas the rear touch panel

Comment: And AFAIK, the Vita sticks cannot be clicked forward like the PS Controller sticks can be.

Answer (score 1):

No, the PSVita can only play PSOne software and supported PS3 software via remote play. However, some HD collections are headed to the Vita as well, namely the Metal Gear Solid and the Zone of the Enders HD collections, and Jet Set Radio as well.

Update: A few of HD remakes have added support for PS Vita via Remote Play, these are ICO, Shadow of the Colussus, God of War & God of War II.